# Spring Data JPA Specification Inheritance `criterialBuilder.treat` not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is the repository

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<DocumentEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DocumentEntity> {

    List<DocumentEntity> findByDossier_Id(Long dossierId);

    default List<DocumentEntity> findByCriteria(Long dossierId, DocumentParent parent, DocumentType type) {
        return findAll((Specification<DocumentEntity>) (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            Root<DocumentEntity> rootDocumentEntity = criteriaBuilder.treat(root, DocumentEntity.class);
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootDocumentEntity.get("dossier_id"), dossierId));
            if (parent == DocumentParent.COMMENT) {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(rootDocumentEntity.get("comment")));
            } else if (parent == DocumentParent.DOSSIER) {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.isNull(rootDocumentEntity.get("comment")));
            }

            if (type != null) {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootDocumentEntity.get("document_type"), type.name()));
            }

            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        });
    }
}
```

This is the parent:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class DomainAudit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4248744229661473649L;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updatedDate;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 255)
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "updated_by", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String updatedBy;

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(LocalDateTime updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

}
```

This class will add those columns into the entity automatically when we persist an entity into the database. So if we want to enable this behavior to a specific table, we just need to extend it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DocumentEntity extends DomainAudit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2917147851986086253L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dossier_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_document_dossier"))
    private DossierEntity dossier;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_document_comment"), nullable = true)
    private CommentEntity comment;

    @Column(name = "document_type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DocumentType documentType;

    @Column(name = "path", nullable = false)
    private String path;

    @Column(name = "original_file_name", nullable = false)
    private String originalFileName;
}
```

I've tried multiple solutions on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529445/spring-data-jpa-specification-inheritance) but non seems to work. It always return this error message:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [dossier_id] on this ManagedType [com.ubitec.sbs.support.DomainAudit]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [dossier_id] on this ManagedType [com.ubitec.sbs.support.DomainAudit]

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.ubitec.sbs.document.DocumentRepository.findByCriteria(DocumentRepository.java:24)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.findByCriteria(Unknown Source)
    at com.ubitec.sbs.document.DocumentServiceTest.should_return_all_documents_of_an_existing_dossier(DocumentServiceTest.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [dossier_id] on this ManagedType [com.ubitec.sbs.support.DomainAudit]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateAttributeInternal(AbstractFromImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:177)
    at com.ubitec.sbs.document.DocumentRepository.lambda$findByCriteria$83732f0e$1(DocumentRepository.java:27)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria(SimpleJpaRepository.java:762)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:693)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:677)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 57 more
```

How can I change it so that `rootDocumentEntity.get("dossier_id")` is really referring to `DocumentEntity`

Comment: Use the name of the property: `"dossier"`

Comment: wow, it works. @JensSchauder can you post your comment so that I can upvote it?

Comment: anwer to myself: remove this line since it's redundant `Root<DocumentEntity> rootDocumentEntity = criteriaBuilder.treat(root, DocumentEntity.class);`, this line also produces `null=null` in the query, and change `dossier_id` to `dossier`, `document_type` to `documentType`, and pass the enum directy instead of calling `type.name()`

Answer (score 2):

Use the name of the property: `"dossier"`.

`"dossier_id"` is a column name (in the database).
With the criteria API you need to use the property names (the ones used in Java).

Comment: I have one more question. it works but doesn't return the answer. With some debug I saw something strange in the `where` clause. It looks like this: `where null=null and documenten0_.dossier_id=1`. Given the above code, with `type=null, parent=ANY`, we only have one `Predicate`. Do you know where the `null = null` comes from?

Comment: No, I don't. But if you remove the various predicates from the code it soon should become obvious where it is coming from. And if that isn't enough to fix it that reduced code with just the problematic predicate could be basis of a new question.

Comment: my bad, now I've figured out the root cause of the error message. `Root<DocumentEntity> rootDocumentEntity = criteriaBuilder.treat(root, DocumentEntity.class);` this is redundant and it produces `null=null`, and query with wrong property name will make the property searching cascaded up to the parent class, that's why I got the error message in the first place. It's all fixed, thank you.